# How to pass both a JSON object on Init and configure ajax for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jstree

I'm upgrading from jsTree 1.0 to jsTree 3.3.4.  With 1.0 I was previously providing a JSON object as the inital load data as well as an ajax configuration for lazy loading:

```
$("#emptyJsTreeDIV").jstree({
    "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "sort", "crrm"],
    "core" : {html_titles": true},
    "sort" : customSortFunctionName,
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : initialLoadJSONTreeData,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "jsTreeLazyLoading/data",
            "data" : id
        }
    }
});
```

With version 3.3.4 json_data was moved to core and the API seems to only accept one or the other option.  Currently, I am passing only the initial load JSON like this:

```
$("#emptyJsTreeDIV").jstree({
    "plugins" : ["sort"],
    "core" : {
        "data": initialLoadJSONTreeData
    }
});
```

How can I also give the ajax configuration for lazy loading?

Comment: Have you tried passing that Ajax config inside the `core` object?

Comment: I hadn't tried that but I just gave it a shot and it didn't work.  Here's the example for configuring AJAX given here.  https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

$('#tree').jstree({
'core' : {
  'data' : {
    'url' : function (node) {
      return node.id === '#' ?
        'ajax_roots.json' :
        'ajax_children.json';
    },
    'data' : function (node) {
      return { 'id' : node.id };
    }
  }
});